# GET Save Queries from log Analytics via Azure API

Tags: api, azure, azure-log-analytics, saved-searches

Hi there i'm trying to get the queries i've saved in log analytics via an API GET Request. and following the guide (even testing it from the Documentation page) doesn't work. I know the queries are there and are saved, am i missing something?

I follow this documentation:
[Microsoft Docs - Saved Searches - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/savedsearches/get)

I Call the API like this:

```
GET 

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{workspaceName}/savedSearches/{savedSearchId}?api-version=2015-03-20

Authorization: Bearer eyJ0...eXAQ
```

And the respons i get is this:

```
404 Not Found

{
    "error": {
        "code": "SavedSearchNotFound",
        "message": "Saved search '[NAME OF MY SAVED QUERY]' could not be found."
    }
}
```

I really cant figure out what the problem is here. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found My Answer:

The "{savedSearchId}" is supposed to be a guid... As i tried to find one at the beginning when constructing the URL i coundn't find an id for each search query. so i thought it was the name of it.

You can find the Query by clicking the three dots to the right of each saved query and click edit.

The query will show the ID for it under the name in Gray text.

[image]